# Combining columns conditionally using data.table in R

Tags: r, combinations, data.table, conditional-statements

I have a dataset that has a set of plants. Two of these plants have multiple lines. When analyzing the data, I'd like to have a column that would have the two plants that have multiple lines put together but all others as they are. Here is my reproducible data set:

```
testset <- data.table(date=as.Date(c("2013-07-02","2013-08-03","2013-09-04","2013-10-05","2013-11-06")), yr = c(2013,2013,2013,2013,2013), mo = c(07,08,09,10,11), da = c(02,03,04,05,06), plant = LETTERS[1:5], PlantID = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,6,7), product = as.factor(letters[26:22]), rating = runif(25))
```

This is the appended column output that I'm looking for:

A1

B2

C3

D4

E5

A1

B2

C3

D6

E7

This is a simple example but my true dataset is much, much larger so I'd like to have an elegant data.table way to produce it.

Comment: Your last column of the reproducible data is broken: it needs to be a multiple of 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this when you use `data.table`'s. Instead, you should set a `key` or use an *ad-hoc* `by` (like I show in the example below). This is one of the key foundations of operations in `data.table`.

---

#### Toy example using `by`:

Look at the toy example below. We sum the rating by the `id` and `grp` variable. So where duplicates exist, they get summed, but unique combinations of the grouping variables will be treated by themselves (so note the value for `rating` and `sum_rating` for the last row which has a unique combination of grouping variables (the other rows have two rows each like in your example):

```
# Make this data reproducible
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table( id = c( rep( 1:2 , 2 ) , 1 ) , grp = c( rep( 1:2 , 2 ) , 3 ) , rating = sample( 5 , 5 , TRUE ) ) 
#   id grp rating
#1:  1   1      4
#2:  2   2      1
#3:  1   1      3
#4:  2   2      4
#5:  1   3      4

# Sum by 'id' and 'grp'...
dt[ , sum_rating := sum( rating ) , by = list( id , grp ) ]
dt
#   id grp rating sum_rating
#1:  1   1      4          7
#2:  2   2      1          5
#3:  1   1      3          7
#4:  2   2      4          5
#5:  1   3      4          4  <=====  rating and sum_rating are the same because this is a unique row
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're desired output is, but hopefully this will help you on the way. Here's a `data.table` solution for finding all the unique plant lines:

```
> testset[,unique(paste0(plant, PlantID))]
[1] "A1" "B2" "C3" "D4" "D6" "E5" "E7"
```